# 16-bit Floating point range of different values

Tags: floating-point

Let's say there is a floating-point code that fit in 16 bits, with 1 bit for the sign and 4 bits for the exponent and the rest (11) for the significad. I've been able to find the range of normalized exponent, which I believe is [-6,7], by calculating 1-bias and 2^(k-1) - 1. However, I'm having trouble finding these:

The median value of the code, the range of positive denormalized values, the range of positive normalized values, the median of the positive normalized values and the median of the positive values.

How can I calculate these? I'm not sure how to approach it.

Comment: But usually, `1111` and `0000` at least are reserved for NaN/infinity and exact zero.

Comment: There are 16 bits. Only $2^{16} \approx 65000$ combinations. You can calculate each value into single or double precision on a PC (both should easily hold half precision float), stuff it in a list and then sort the list.

Comment: IEEE 754 has more negative than positive exponents, so range $[-7,6]$.